# Spring Cloud Gateway with CircuitBreaker

Tags: spring, cloud, gateway

I am getting following exception while starting Gateway spring boot Application

ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CircuitBreaker

filter configuration is
filters:
- name: CircuitBreaker
args:
name: MicroService
fallback: forward:/fallbackurl

Does any one has idea how can this be fixed.
``